# MA(q) model throwing an error

Tags: r, time-series

So here is the code to create an MA(q) model that takes in values 'thetas', 'sigsq', and 'T'.

```
masim <- function(thetas, sigsq, T)
{
  q <- length(thetas)

  noise <- rnorm(T+q, sd=sqrt(sigsq))
  x <- c(noise[1:q], rep(0,T))
  for( i in (q+1):(T+q)){
    x[i] <- thetas %*% x[i-(1:q)] + noise[i]
  }
x <- x[(q+1):(T+q)]
x
}
```

Now if I run an autocorrelation on `masim` like this for example:

```
acf(masim(0.5,1,10000))
```

It works fine, with a great ACF plot. However if I run this example:

```
acf(masim(2,1,10000))
```

Then I get this error.

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

My coding partner next to me got both of his to work.

Comment: Did you check the output of  `masim(2,1,10000)`? You can also check the output of `table(masim(2,1,10000))`.

Comment: I was able to fix the errors on my own.

Comment: You could share your fix as an answer.